# How to not to add new line at the end in OS X with SED

Tags: macos, sed

I have a script that finds all *.mvel files and replaces "D1000" with "D4000". But sed adds new line at the end. How could I avoid new line at the end of file?

Here is my script:

```
find . -name '*.mvel' -exec sed -i '' 's/D1000/D4000/g' '{}' \;
```

Comment: To be honest, I do not know the syntax. I would be very grateful if someone will tell me how to do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654021/how-can-i-delete-a-newline-if-it-is-the-last-character-in-a-file

Comment: Stephane thank you! But could you show the final solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using `perl`

```
perl -pe 'chomp if eof' filename >filename2
```

is what I successfully tested to remove the ending \n on a file