# How to identify files which have empty new lines at the bottom of the file

Tags: regex, eclipse

I have several files which either have 2 or 3 or more empty lines at the bottom of the of the file. How do I find all such files and remove the empty lines in a automated fashion.

Comment: What language or tool? and What have you tried?

Comment: Just a note, I always like to keep one empty line at the end of the file. It makes it easier when you do something on the server like "cat > filename.php"... then when it's done pasting you can just hit Ctrl-D and it saves and exits cat. I know it's petty, I might as well hit enter before ctrl-d, but hey... I like saving keystrokes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex with **dotall option** selected

```
^(\r?\n){2,}$
```

and replace it with **nothing**

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to trim the trailing blank lines.  The first that comes to mind is:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{ undef $/} 1 while s/\n\n$/\n/'
```

To find and replace files, you could do:

```
find /base/directory -type f -exec perl -i -pe 'BEGIN{ undef $/} 1 while s/\n\n$/\n/' {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

using a bash shell, this will test all files in the current directory and print only those with 2 or more trailing newlines:

```
for f in `ls *`; do if [ "$(tail -2 $f | tr '\n' 'x')" = "xx" ]; then echo $f; fi; done
```

**TIP:** replace the initial `ls *` with `find . -type f` to recursively search through subdirectories

Try this [separate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654021/how-can-i-delete-a-newline-if-it-is-the-last-character-in-a-file) for commands that remove trailing newlines from a file.