# Removing a newline character at the end of a file

Tags: bash, scripting, newline, tr

To remove all newlines you could, say:

```
tr -d '\n' < days.txt
cat days.txt | tr -d '\n'
```

but how would you use `tr` to remove just the newline at the end/bottom of a text file?

I'm not sure to specify just the last one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I delete a newline if it is the last character in a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654021/how-can-i-delete-a-newline-if-it-is-the-last-character-in-a-file)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Take advantage of the fact that a) the newline character is at the end of the file and b) the character is 1 byte large: use the `truncate` command to shrink the file by one byte:

```
# a file with the word "test" in it, with a newline at the end (5 characters total)
$ cat foo 
test

# a hex dump of foo shows the '\n' at the end (0a)
$ xxd -p foo
746573740a

# and `stat` tells us the size of the file: 5 bytes (one for each character)
$ stat -c '%s' foo
5

# so we can use `truncate` to set the file size to 4 bytes instead
$ truncate -s 4 foo

# which will remove the newline at the end
$ xxd -p foo
74657374
$ cat foo
test$
```

You can also roll the sizing and math into a one line command:

```
truncate -s $(($(stat -c '%s' foo)-1)) foo
```

Answer (score 94):

A simpler solution than the accepted one:

```
truncate -s -1 <<file>>
```

From the `truncate` man page (`man truncate`):

```
-s, --size=SIZE
    set or adjust the file size by SIZE
SIZE may also be prefixed by one of the following modifying characters:
    '+' extend by, '-' reduce by, '<' at most, '>' at least, '/' round down
    to multiple of, '%' round up to multiple of.
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a simple solution. A lot of these “Unix” approaches that rely on some side-effect or quirk of filtering or processing things in sed/awk/perl are not really simple.

Answer (score 29):

If you are sure the last character is a new-line, it is very simple:

```
head -c -1 days.txt
```

`head -c -N` means *everything except for the last N bytes*

If you want to **modify the file in-place**:

```
truncate -s -1 days.txt
```

It will remove the last byte of the file, regardless of what it is.

Comment: got `head: illegal byte count -- -1` on OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 :(

Comment: same on MacOS High Sierra 10.13. `illegal byte count`

Comment: For MacOS you need to `brew install coreutils` and use `ghead`.

Comment: This solution does not do it in-place.

Comment: @ks1322: I just added a solution for that problem too.

Answer (score 16):

I think your best bet is Perl:

```
perl -0pe 's/\n\Z//' days.txt
```

The `-0` causes perl to treat the whole file as one big string. The `-p` tells it to print that string back out after running the program on it. And the `-e` says "here's the program to run".

The regular expression `\n\Z` matches a newline, but only if it's the last character in a string. And `s/\n\Z//` says to replace such a newline with nothing at all, deleting it.

The above command outputs the new version of the file, but you can instead modify the existing one by adding the `-i` ("in-place") option, optionally with a suffix that will be used to name a backup copy of the file before modifying it:

```
 perl -i.bak -0pe 's/\n\Z//' days.txt
```

This solution is safe in that if the last character is *not* a newline, it won't be touched.  The other solutions which simply remove the last byte no matter what may corrupt such a file.

Comment: This works on macOS as well, unless `truncate` or `head -c -1`.

Answer (score 9):

Try this command:
`sed '$ { /^$/ d}' days.txt`

You can read it as: "check if last line is an empty line. if so delete this line".
I tested with both cases: first with a file having a new line at the end and an other time with a file ending with something else.

Comment: Even better with `sed`'s in-place mode: sed -i '$ { /^$/ d}' days.txt

Answer (score 7):

Another Sed solution:

```bash
sed -z s/.$// days.txt
```

The `-z` option is to interpret the file as a single long string (newlines are embedded as `\n`), then `s` matches the single character `.` before the end of line (= end of file) `$`, and changes it into nothing. No need for quoting the command.

If you are not sure the last character is a newline, then you do either of these:

```bash
sed -z s/\\n$// days.txt
sed -z 's/\n$//' days.txt
```

Comment: This seems to be the right solution to me. (Lynch's solution only works for an empty line, the other solutions need to know there's a newline). But it doesn't work for some reason. Newline is still there in my case.

Comment: You have to `> days2.txt` or to add the `-i` option of your seed flavor supports it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the newline at the end of the file, you can use:

`truncate -s -1 file_name.txt`

The change will be saved in the file.