# How to remove EOF empty line created by sed

Tags: bash, macos, awk, sed, scripting

I'm using sed to modify the first part of a text file. The problem is that sed automatically introduces a empty line at the end of the file.

Do you know how to solve that? (Not using truncate, as I do not want to install additional software in MacOS)

Thanks!!

Comment: Please show us samples input and sample outputs in code tags in your post.

Comment: Sed introduces EOF empty line anyway you use it @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @MMManuel I updated my answer a bit, I hope it explains it and tells you how to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick answer to your question would be to pipe your output to another cmd like `awk`:

```
sed 'commands' file | awk '(NR>1){printf "%s\n",l}{l=$0}END{printf "%s",l}'
```

This will remove the last `<newline>`. This cannot be done by `sed`, the answer below tries to explain it. More possibilities can be found in [How can I delete a newline if it is the last character in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654021/how-can-i-delete-a-newline-if-it-is-the-last-character-in-a-file)

**Why does `sed` always finishes with a `<newline>`?**
The answer to this question depends on the interpretation of the standard and the implementation of `sed` you use.

According to the [`sed` posix standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html):

> In default operation, *`sed` cyclically shall append a line of input,
>   less its terminating `<newline>` character, into the pattern space.*
>   Reading from input shall be skipped if a `<newline>` was in the pattern
>   space prior to a `D` command ending the previous cycle. The sed utility
>   shall then apply in sequence all commands whose addresses select that
>   pattern space, until a command starts the next cycle or quits. If no
>   commands explicitly started a new cycle, then at the end of the script
>   the pattern space shall be copied to standard output (except when `-n`
>   is specified) and the pattern space shall be deleted. *Whenever the
>   pattern space is written to standard output or a named file, `sed` shall
>   immediately follow it with a `<newline>`.*

This means two things:

- a line is not processed if it is not terminated by a `<newline>`.
- anything written to standard output is terminated with a `<newline>`, i.e. output as a result of the end of the command cycle, or the issuing of commands `p` or `P`.

Example: `sed (SunOS 5.10) SUNWcsu 11.10.0 rev=2005.01.21.15.53`

```
$ echo -n foo | sed 'p'
$ echo -n 'foo\nbar' | sed 'p'                                                                                                                                                                                                
foo
foo
```

There is clearly no processing if the lines that are not terminated by a `<newline>`. Otherwise `<newlines>` are added at any output.

The [MacOS `sed` manual](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html) has a similar interpration as posix.

> Normally, `sed` cyclically copies a line of input, not including its
>   terminating newline character, into
>        a pattern space, (unless there is something left after a `D` function), applies all of the commands
>        with addresses that select that pattern space, copies the pattern space to the standard output, append-ing appending
>        ing a newline, and deletes the pattern space.

This is not tested as I do not have a mac.

The [GNU `sed` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Execution-Cycle) seems to have a slightly different perspective on the matter:

> `sed` operates by performing the following cycle on each line of input:
>   first, sed reads one line from the input stream, removes any trailing
>   newline, and places it in the pattern space. Then commands are
>   executed; each command can have an address associated to it: addresses
>   are a kind of condition code, and a command is only executed if the
>   condition is verified before the command is to be executed.
>
> When the end of the script is reached, unless the `-n` option is in use, the contents of pattern space are printed out to the output stream, adding back the trailing newline if it was removed.

Which implies the following :

- all lines are processed, all or not terminated by a `<newline>`
- if the end of the command cycle is reached, the same amount of  `<newline>`'s is added as was initially removed.

Example : `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`

In the following example, a newline is only added after `p` and not after the end of the cycle. (newline is `012` in hex)

```
    $ echo -n foo | hexdump -b
    0000000 146 157 157                                                    
    0000003
    $ echo -n foo | sed --posix 'p' | hexdump -b
    0000000 146 157 157 012 146 157 157                                    
    0000007
```

This is explained by [Footnote 7](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#FOOT7) :

> Actually, if `sed` prints a line without the terminating newline, it
>   will nevertheless print the missing newline as soon as more text is
>   sent to the same output stream, which gives the “least expected
>   surprise” even though it does not make commands like `sed -n p`
>   exactly identical to `cat`.

**In conclusion:** according to the [posix standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), you will always end up with an output file finishing with a `<newline>`, it might however not be the last line of the input. According the the [Gnu manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Execution-Cycle), your output terminates with the same amount of  you have at the end of your input file.

**Question:** is GNU's `sed --posix` real posix?