# Delete last line break using sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed, file-manipulation, end-of-line

How to delete the last `\n` from a file. The file has a **last blank line** created for a line break in the last text line. I'm using this command:

```
sed '/^\s*$/d'
```

But that las blank line is not removed.

Comment: Your sed might not understand `\s`. Try the POSIX character class `[[:blank:]]` instead.

Comment: `delete the last \n from a file` - do you mean you want to delete last line if it is empty or do you mean to remove the `\n` character from last line whether it is empty or not..

Answer (score 4):

**Why is `sed` printing a newline?**

When you read the [`sed` POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), then it states:

> Whenever the pattern space is written to standard output or a named file, `sed` shall immediately follow it with a `<newline>`.

A bit more details can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49385467/8344060).

**Removing the last `<newline>`:**

- **`truncate`:** If you want to delete just one-character from a file you can do :

  ```
  truncate -s -1 <file>
  ```

  This makes the file one byte shorter, i.e. remove the last character.

  > From **`man resize`**:
  >   `-s, --size=SIZE`        set or adjust the file size by `SIZE` bytes
  >
  > `SIZE` may also be prefixed by one of the following modifying characters:
  >   '`+`' extend by, '`-`' reduce by, '`<`' at most, '`>`' at least,
  >   '`/`' round down to multiple of, '`%`' round up to multiple of.
- other answers can be found in [How can I delete a newline if it is the last character in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654021/how-can-i-delete-a-newline-if-it-is-the-last-character-in-a-file)

Answer (score 1):

**1) DELETE LAST EMPTY LINE FROM A FILE:**

First of all, the command you are currently using will delete ***ALL*** empty and blank lines!

***NOT ONLY THE LAST ONE.***

If you want to delete the last line if it is empty/blank then you can use the following command:

```
sed '${/^[[:blank:]]*$/d}' test
```

**INPUT:**

```
cat -vTE test                                                                                                                  
a$
$
b$
$
c$
^I ^I $
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
sed '${/^[[:blank:]]*$/d}' test                                                                                                
a

b

c
```

**Explanations:**

- the first `$` will tell `sed` to do the processing only on the last line
- `/^[[:blank:]]*$/` the condition will be evaluate by sed and if this line is empty or composed only of blank chars it will trigger the delete operation on the pattern buffer, therefore this last line will not be printed
- you can redirect the output of the sed command to save it to a new file or do the changes in-place using `-i` option (**if you use it take a back up of your file!!!!**) or use `-i.bak` to force `sed` to take a back up of your file before modifying it.

**IMPORTANT:**

If your file comes from Windows and contain some carriage returns (`\r`) this `sed` command will not work!!! You will need to remove those noisy characters by using either `dos2unix` or `tr -d '\r'`.

For files containing carriage returns `<CR>` (`\r` or `^M`):

**BEFORE FIXING THE FILE:**

**cat:**

```
cat -vTE test 
a$
$
b$
$
c$
^I ^I ^M$
```

**od:**

```
od -c test 
0000000   a  \n  \n   b  \n  \n   c  \n  \t      \t      \r  \n
0000016
```

**sed:**

```
sed '${/^[[:blank:]]*$/d}' test                                                                                                
a

b

c
```

**AFTER FIXING THE FILE:**

```
dos2unix test 
dos2unix: converting file test to Unix format ...
```

**cat:**

```
cat -vTE test                                                                                                                  
a$
$
b$
$
c$
^I ^I $
```

**od:**

```
od -c test 
0000000   a  \n  \n   b  \n  \n   c  \n  \t      \t      \n
0000015
```

**sed:**

```
sed '${/^[[:blank:]]*$/d}' test                                                                                                
a

b

c
```

**2) DELETE LAST EOL CHARACTER FROM A FILE:**

For this particular purpose, I would recommend using `perl`:

```
perl -pe 'chomp if eof' test
a

b

c
```

you can add `-i` option to to the change `in-place` (take a backup of your file before running the command). Last but not least, you might have to remove Carriage Return from your files as described hereover.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear but this might be what you're asking for:

```
$ cat file
a
b
c

$ awk 'NR>1{print p} {p=$0}' file
a
b
c
$
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice awk solution! +1!

Answer (score 1):

you can also use below one-liner from `sed` to remove the trailing blank line(s):

`sed -e :a -e '/^\n*$/N;/\n$/ba'`