# How to remove the last linefeed from a stream

Tags: macos, sed, command-line-interface

I have a program that always adds a newline character to a file/stream. I want to remove this last linefeed.

However, on the command line this seams very difficult. When a stream ends with an empty line, this works perfectly:

```
printf $'line 1\nline 2\n\n' | sed '${/^$/d;}'
```

However, when there is only one linefeed at the end, sed doesn't do a thing:

```
printf $'line 1\nline 2\n' | sed '${/^$/d;}'
```

So how to remove this last *newline* character...

It should work on the command line of macOS. I think it's save to assume the line always will end with a newline character, but if there is a solution that will test for this new line that would be preferable. And also the solution doesn't need to use `sed`....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50559170/delete-last-line-break-using-sed/50559827#50559827

Comment: Use `perl` as `.. | perl -pe 'chomp if eof'` (took it from one of the answers from above)

Comment: @Inian: deleted!

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right question/answer. I wouldn't have found it without you guys... 