# How to remove starting newlines or the starting new from a binary file?

Tags: python, shell, perl, sed, command-line

I see there are discussions about removing trailing newlines.

[How can I delete a newline if it is the last character in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654021/how-can-i-delete-a-newline-if-it-is-the-last-character-in-a-file)

But I don't find a discusion about removing starting newlines. Could anybody let me know what is the best way to delete starting newlines (one liner preferred)? Thanks.

Comment: `lstrip()` ? `replace` can also help

Comment: Do you want to remove all initial blank lines, or just the first one?

Comment: Both are needed.

Comment: Can you give a small input example?

Comment: Also, why the _one liner preferred_?

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent-opposite Perl code to `chomp` is `s/^\n//`. Instead of doing it on the last line (eof), do it on the first line. Even though it will only be an empty line, removing the newline will mean that line will print nothing in the output.

```
perl -pe 's/^\n// if $. == 1' filename >filename2
```

or in place:

```
perl -pi -e 's/^\n// if $. == 1' filename
```

Since starting newlines are by definition empty lines, you can also just skip printing them by using `-n` instead of `-p` (same behavior but without printing, so you can determine which lines to print).

```
perl -ni -e 'print unless $. == 1 and m/^\n/' filename
```

If you want to remove potentially multiple starting newlines, you could take another approach; advance the handle yourself in the beginning until you receive a non-empty line.

```
perl -pi -e 'if ($. == 1) { $_ = <> while m/^\n/ }' filename
```

It's all much easier if you don't mind reading the entire file into memory at once rather than line by line:

```
perl -0777 -pi -e 's/^\n+//' filename
```

To avoid doing any excess work editing the file unless it starts with newline characters, you could condition the edit by prefixing it with another command (reads first line of the file and causes a non-zero exit status if it doesn't start with a newline):

```
perl -e 'exit 1 unless <> =~ m/^\n/' filename && perl ...
```

Comment: Instead of substituting, just skip the line if it's just a newline.

Comment: But I guess that would require using something other than the simple `perl -pie` loop.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, you can't skip lines in `-p` as `$_` is always printed. But you can take that approach with `-n` - will add to the answer.

Comment: Also, the question says starting newlines -- plural. I asked for clarification, though.

Comment: I don't quite following this `perl -pi -e 'if ($. == 1) { $_ = <> while m/^\n/ }' filename`. Could you please explain how it works? Thanks.

Comment: @user1424739 Only on the first line, when `$.` (current line number) will be 1, it will call `<>` again (this is done implicitly by `-p` or `-n` normally) until the current line is more than just a newline. `<>` is [readline](https://perldoc.pl/functions/readline) and will read the next line from `*ARGV` which will be the file passed on the command line.

Comment: Of all the inplace solutions here, I'd make sure it terminates immediately when the input contains no starting newline. This is critical for large input files. Do the solutions terminate immediate once it checks that there is not starting newlines?

Comment: @user1424739 Terminating immediately would mean the rest of the file would be omitted from the output. All of these solutions pass through the rest of the file unchanged.

Comment: @user1424739 It's important to remember that you can't actually edit files in place except for appending or byte-for-byte with a hex editor - "in place editing" in text is really just creating a whole new slightly different text file, and then copying it over the original.

Comment: @user1424739 For a solution that decides whether to edit the file first, it is probably better to step out of oneliner territory and use something like [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny).

Comment: Or make it a two command process, check for starting newlines and then edit.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, start reading the file without writing in a loop until you get a non-empty line.

```
outdata = ""
with open(filename) as infile:
    while True:
        line = infile.readline()
        if line != "\n":
            break
    if line:
        outdata = line # save first non-empty line
    outdata += infile.read() # save the rest of the file
with open(filename, "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(outdata)
```

Comment: Make sure to handle reaching eof without any non-empty lines

Comment: @Grinnz Added an `if`. That should work because it returns an empty string at EOF.

Comment: Concatenate all the lines that would have been written to a string. Then close the infile and write the string back to the original file.

Comment: @user1424739 What do you mean by _inplace editing of the original file_?

Comment: @AMC He means he wants to replace the file instead of creating a new file.

Comment: @Barmar yes. that is what I mean.

Comment: You can also simply rename `newfiename` to `filename` after the loop.

Comment: I've updated the answer to overwrite the file in place

Answer (score 0):

Simple filter to skip leading empty lines

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $begin = 1;

while( <> ) {
        next if /^$/ and $begin;
        $begin = 0;
        say;
}
```

One liner version `perl -0777 -pe 's/^\n+//' filename`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, I'm sure it can still be improved a bit.

```py
with open('../resources/temp_in.txt', 'r+') as file:
    overwrite = False
    for line in file:
        if line:
            overwrite = True
            first_line = line
            break
    if overwrite:
        contents = first_line + file.read()
        file.seek(0)
        file.write(contents)
        file.truncate()
```

---

Here is an alternative solution, which opens the file twice.

```py
with open('../resources/temp_in.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.strip():
            contents = line + file.read()
            break
    else:
        contents = ''

with open('../resources/temp_in.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(contents)
```

Comment: When is it better to use seek? When is it better to just close the file and reopen it?

Comment: @user1424739 _When is it better to use seek?_ As opposed to what? _When is it better to just close the file and reopen it?_ That depends, how does closing and reopening fit into the rest of the potential solution?

Comment: The solution could be open the file, read the content into a variable, close the file, strip the leading newlines in the variable, open the file again, save the content of the variable into the file and close it. How is this different from your current solution performance wise. In other words, it is faster to seek or just close the file and reopen it?

Comment: @user1424739 Hmm, good question I guess since I’m reading/writing practically the entire file regardless, it shouldn’t make that much of a difference. I’ll whip up a quick solution.

Comment: @user1424739 See my edit. Do you have any test data, to ensure it works perfectly?

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag when you find a line that's not just a newline and print when that flag is set:

```
awk '/./{f=1}f' file
```

e.g.:

```
$ printf '\n\n\nfoo\nbar\n'



foo
bar

$ printf '\n\n\nfoo\nbar\n' | awk '/./{f=1}f'
foo
bar
```