# ldapsearch with -y option throws 'Invalid credentials' error

Tags: linux, bash, macos, ldap

I have kept my LDAP password in `$HOME/.ldap_pw` on my Mac. The file has permissions set to 600:

```
-rw-------  1 myself  mygroup  18 Mar 27 17:20 .ldap_pw
```

When I invoke `ldapsearch` with `-y` option like this, to list the members of the group `mygroup`

```
ldapsearch -y "$HOME/.ldap_pw" -H ldaps://ldap.mycompany.com -D myself@mycompany.com -W -b DC=mycompany,DC=com -x '(&(objectcategory=Group)(cn=mygroup))'
```

I get this error:

```
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
    additional info: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090442, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v3839
```

The password stored in the file is correct.  Also, the above command works fine when run without the `-y` option with password being entered when prompted.

What is going wrong here?

I get the same error on my Linux box running RedHat 7.6.

Comment: Do you get the same error using `-w <password>` in stead of using `-y <passwdfile>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think SmartTom's guess about an extra character in the file is a good one. Try running `hd ~/.ldap_pw` (`h`ex `d`ump) to see the exact contents of the file; if there's a trailing `0a` (newline) character or other unexpected characters that would confirm the issue.

Editors like `vim` implicitly add a trailing newline to text files, which you can [disable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1050640/113632) when opening the file, or you can [remove trailing whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1654021/113632) directly.

Answer (score 4):

Given the error, that means that the username is valid but password invalid (see [ldapwiki.com](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Common%20Active%20Directory%20Bind%20Errors)) and the fact that `-y` use the **complete contents** of the file (see [ldapsearch documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ldapsearch)), I suspect a wrong content in your password file. Maybe an "End of line" character at the end of your file.