# How to remove newline from the end of a file using Perl

Tags: perl, newline

I have a file that reads like this:

```
dog   cat   mouse
apple    orange    pear
red    yellow    green
```

There is a tab `\t` separating the words on each row, and a newline `\n` separating each of the rows. Below the last line, `red   yellow   green` there is a blank line due to a newline `\n` after `green`.
I would like to use Perl to remove the newline.

I have seen a few articles like this [How can I delete a newline if it is the last character in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654021/how-can-i-delete-a-newline-if-it-is-the-last-character-in-a-file) that give solutions for Perl, but I would like to do this in hard code so that I can incorporate it into my Perl script.
I don't know if this might be possible using chomp, or if chomp works on each line separately (I would like to keep the newline between lines).

Also I have seen previously comments that suggest maintaining a newline at the end of a file because Unix commands work better when a file ends with a newline. However, I have created a script which relies on input files not ending with a newline, therefore I really feel removing the newlines is necessary for my work.

Comment: Why does your script rely on a file not ending with newline? That sounds like a poor script to me.

Comment: Something like this will work, the chmp removes new lines, the split is on one of more white save. The -lane processes the file a line at a time, inline.
perl -lane 'chomp; if ($_) {@list=split(/\s+/); print join("|",@list);}' file1

Comment: does `od -c yourfile | tail` end with `g r e e n \n` or `g r e e n \n \n` ?

Comment: @TLP I created the script before I knew files were supposed to end with a newline, and much of the script involves count the number of lines. Why is it bad form to not end with a newline?

Comment: @EssexBoy `-l` already does chomp and `-a` does autosplit: `perl -lanE '$_ && say join "|",@F'`

Comment: @jhnc The end of the file looks like this:
0017360  \n
0017361
So just a single \n I believe

Comment: If there's a blank line, that would imply that there are 2 `\n` after green.  If there is only one `\n`, there is no blank line.

Comment: @WilliamPursell There does appear to be a blank link though.

Comment: If there's a blank line, then there are two newlines after `green`.  You almost certainly want to keep one of them.  The file with content `one\ntwo\n` has two lines.  The file with content `one\ntwo\n\n` has 3 lines, and one of them is blank.  The file with content `one\ntwo` is barely even describable as a text file, and is more accurately described as ill formed garbage.

Comment: Note that the above comment is highly opinionated.  A text file does not need to end with a newline, but IMO they ought to.  If you have a utility that treats `one\ntwo\n` as a three line file, that utility is broken.

Comment: Fix your program to handle a newline at the end of any line. You are eventually going to run into problems where editors re-add the newline. Instead of duct-taping over the problem, don't make it a problem. Consider the pain people experience in this issue: https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues/1753

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
perl -pe 'chomp if eof' file.txt
```

Here is another simple way, if you need it in a script:

```
open $fh, "file.txt"; 
@lines=<$fh>;          # read all lines and store in array 
close $fh;
chomp $lines[-1];      # remove newline from last line
print @lines;
```

Or something like this (in script), as suggested by jnhc for the command line:

```
open $fh, "file.txt"; 
while (<$fh>) { 
  chomp if eof $fh; 
  print; 
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: Could you give any guidance as to how to do this - or if not, explain what the aspects of your code do?

Comment: `perl -pe 'chomp if eof' file.txt` is a bit shorter

Comment: I used `open $fh, "file.txt"; 
while (<$fh>) { 
  chomp if eof $fh; 
  print; 
}
close $fh;` and that did the trick