# match and replace multiple newlines with a SED or PERL one-liner

Tags: perl, sed, newline, replace, multiline

I have an input C file (myfile.c) that looks like this :

```
void func_foo();
void func_bar();

//supercrazytag
```

I want to use a shell command to insert new function prototypes, such that the output becomes:

```
void func_foo();
void func_bar();
void func_new();

//supercrazytag
```

So far I've been unsuccessful using SED or PERL.
What didn't work:

```
sed 's|\n\n//supercrazytag|void func_new();\n\n//supercrazytag|g' < myfile.c
sed 's|(\n\n//supercrazytag)|void func_new();\1|g' < myfile.c
```

Using the same patterns with perl -pe "....." didn't work either.

What am I missing ? I've tried many different approaches, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164925/match-any-character-including-newlines-in-sed) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n/1252191#1252191) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577057/sed-find-pattern-over-two-lines-not-replace-after-that-pattern).

Comment: You should not really be using `sed` here since it reads line per line basis, `awk` is a much better solution. Pick a tool that does your task and does it well, for this `sed` does not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For "perl -pe", your problem is that it is processing line by line, so there is no way it will find "\n\n".  If you add the -0777 flag to Perl (to make it process the whole file at once) it will work:

```
perl -0777 -pe "s|(\n\n//supercrazytag)|\nvoid func_new();$1|g" myfile.c
```

I also changed the (deprecated for this usage) \1 to $1 and added an extra "\n" to beginning of the replacement for readability.

See [perlrun (Command Switches)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) for an explanation of the odd-looking "-0777"

Comment: This is really super easy to read (except the -0777, which looks a bit odd as you've said), but sed and friends don't come close to this simple syntax.

Comment: This worked. However, it was printing the result to screen, not changing the actual file. Use `-i` like `perl -0777 -i -pe "s|(\n\n//supercrazytag)|\nvoid func_new();$1|g" myfile.c` to have it actually change the file

Comment: Another option is to redirect to a different file with > filename

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
sed '/^$/N;s|\n//supercrazytag|void func_new();\n\n//supercrazytag|' myfile.c
```

**EDIT**:
Or more concisely:

```
sed '/^$/N;s|\(\n//supercrazytag\)|void func_new();\n\1|' myfile.c
```

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n/1252191#1252191) for a great explanation of whats going on in the above snippets, though the example at the link isn't identical.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually [an adaptation of an answer I just gave here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365053/how-to-write-from-n-th-row-to-a-file-using-perl/3365299#3365299), on detecting a certain point in a file.

In pseudocode:
1. start reading and writing lines from the file
2. when we find the end of the prototype section, insert some new text

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $new_prototype = 'void func_new();';
my $seen_proto;

while (<>)
{
    if (/^void \w+\(\);$/ .. /^$/)
    {
        # in the middle of the prototype section
        $seen_proto = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        # this code is run when either before or after the prototype section

        # if we have seen prototypes, we're just after that section - print
        # out the new prototype and then reset our flag so we don't do it twice
        print "$new_prototype\n" and $seen_proto-- if $seen_proto;
    }

    # print out the original line
    print;
}
```

Put this code in process.pl and run via:  `perl process.pl < mycode.cpp > mycode_new.cpp`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk  '/supercrazy/{$0="void func_new()\n\n"$0}1'  file
```