# Multiline replace with sed - Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Original file looks like this:

```
BLABLA ABCABC blabl=
a blabla blabla ABC=
ABC blabla blabla A=
BCABC blabla
```

The result should look like:

```
BLABLA DEFDEF blabl=
a blabla blabla DEF=
DEF blabla blabla D=
EFDEF blabla
```

So all `ABCABC` should be replaced by `DEFDEF`, even if there is a linebreak (marked with `=`) in the word.

Is it possible with sed?

Comment: Try with Perl: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365260/match-and-replace-multiple-newlines-with-a-sed-or-perl-one-liner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sed multiline that works for hyphenating `ABCABC` at an arbitrary position:

```
$ sed -r 'N;s/A(=\n)?B(=\n)?C(=\n)?A(=\n)?B(=\n)?C/D\1E\2F\3D\4E\5F/g;P;D' infile
BLABLD AEFDEF blabl=
a blabla blabla DEF=
DEF blabla blabla D=
EFDEF blabla
```

`N;P;D` is the idiomatic way of keeping two lines at a time in the pattern space. The substitution checks for `ABCABC` optionally interspersed with `=` and a newline at any position, and the substitution inserts back what was captured.

This requires extended regular expressions (`-E` in BSD sed) for the `?` operator. GNU sed supports `\?` in BRE as an extension, though, but all the `()` would have to be escaped as well.

---

In case the `=` just *symbolizes* a newline and isn't actually there, this simplifies to

```
$ sed -r 'N;s/A(\n?)B(\n?)C(\n?)A(\n?)B(\n?)C/D\1E\2F\3D\4E\5F/g;P;D' infile
BLABLA DEFDEF blabl
a blabla blabla DEF
DEF blabla blabla D
EFDEF blabla
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not multiline, but solves Your example:

```
sed -r -e 's/ABC/DEF/g' -e 's/AB=/DE=/g' -e 's/A=/D=/g' -e 's/^BC/EF/g' -e 's/^C/F/g' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
sed -i -e "s/ABC/DEF/g;s/A/D/g;s/B/E/g;s/C/F/g" filename.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using gnu awk with null `RS` you can do this in single replacement (using `gensub`):

```
awk -v RS= '{
   print gensub(/A(=\n)?B(=\n)?C(=\n)?A(=\n)?B(=\n)?C/, "D\\1E\\2F\\3D\\4E\\5F", "g", $0)
}' file
```

**Output:**

```
BLABLA DEFDEF blabl=
a blabla blabla DEF=
DEF blabla blabla D=
EFDEF blabla
```